# Why isn't oembed showing the youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, google-api, oembed

Why isn't oembed showing the youtube video? 
I'm using the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>FriendsConnect | Find Friends</title>
<!--Start FC online dependincies-->
<script src="http://friendsconnect.org/jquery_custom/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://friendsconnect.org/jquery_custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://friendsconnect.org/jquery_custom/css/fc-blue/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../secure_serv/users/oembed/jquery.oembed.js"></script>
<!--End FC online dependancies-->
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").button();
    $(".radio").buttonset();

            $(".oembed").oembed("http://www.flickr.com/photos/14516334@N00/345009210/");
    $("input:button").button();
  });
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 83px;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 144px;
        }
        #Button1
        {
            font-size: 9px;
        }
        a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #091419;
}
a:visited {
  color: #091419;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #091419;
}
    </style>
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {background-color: transparent;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INVdbXTuPVI&feature=feedu" class="oembed">ssss</a>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And for some reason it won't show the embedded player. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because some videos are not oembed/json enabled.

If you try to embed http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDOYN-6gdRE, it works. But the video you are trying to embed http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INVdbXTuPVI doesn't work.

You get 401 Unauthorized for the first link and json data for the second link below:

http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INVdbXTuPVI
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDOYN-6gdRE

See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14377 for more details on this.

Comment: You are correct, after I looked into it further I found that the video wasn't embeddable. (If that's a word lol)

Comment: oEmbed doesn't return the correct thumbnail though. Example "INVdbXTuPVI". It says `"thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INVdbXTuPVI/hqdefault.jpg"`. But the correct one is: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INVdbXTuPVI/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAD2_MVMUlE](https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAD2_MVMUlE) gives 401 Unauthorized, but other videos by that uploader do not. (I think your example no longer gives 401.)