# Get youtube info with php

Tags: php, jackson

I want get in my site this text info:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/IyBvgi4ZlbM
```

when the video is  not found.

how i can writte the code?

i don't understand here:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php?csw=1
```

thank you!

Comment: I got the response http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/0KSOMA3QBU0. Your video id is invalid http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyBvgi4ZlbM

Comment: yes is invalid... i whant this text "Video not found" to see abrove all invalid video in my site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a video exists on YouTube, using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try checking the video is available or not with `headers`:

```
$headers = get_headers("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$row['youtube']);

if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) 
{
    echo "Video is not found";
}
```

Comment: good... new i need add this but got error " $headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'<? echo $row['youtube'];?>'); "

Comment: got...    Warning: get_headers(): This function may only be used against URLs in /home/swapes/domains/swapes.com/public_html/cppx/page_youtube.php on line 125 Video is not found

Comment: You missed `http://` :) Try this line `$headers = get_headers("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$row['youtube']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
<?php
$headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/IyBvgi4ZlbM');
$is_ok = substr($headers[0], 9, 3) == 200;

if($is_ok){
    echo 'Video is OK :)';
}
else{
    echo 'Something is wrong :(';
}
```

Comment: No longer available