# How to check if video has been deleted or removed in youtube using python

Tags: youtube-api, python-3.6

i have a csv file where i have 1000 videos links . I want to check whether these videos still exists or they have been removed or deleted from YouTube. How can i do that in python?

Please guide on this

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **[Official Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python)** for Python.

There's a similar question for this problem in Stackoverflow, but meant for PHP (check [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-using-php)).

Comment: Just a heads up that reference is for YouTube API v2 which is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the Video Link Checker plugin that does this for YouTube, DailyMotion, Vimeo, etc.

I can't help with Python code but I can tell you there are a few things to check for each video. 1st you'll need to query the YouTube API [videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint in batches of 50 videoIDs max, then check the results. Here are a couple of tips:

1. Check the `videoIDs` of the items returned against what was requested. Those missing have been deleted from YouTube.
2. For the videos returned, you should still check fields like `privacyStatus`, `embeddable`, and  `regionRestriction` to see if video is still playable. It's not uncommon for those to change.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

this is my code as a function.

```
    def getutl(a="youtubeurl"):
          a=str(a)
          for i in enumerate(a):
               if i[2]="v":
                  idy=a[:i[1]]
                  break
          b=requests.get("http://img.youtube.com/vi/{}/mqdefault.jpg".format(idy))
          if b==200:
               print("video exists")
          else:
              print("video doesn't exists")
```