# Getting oembed using YoutubeURL returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: youtube-api

For A few days, I have suddenly become receiving the 403 Forbidden response from `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url={youtubeURl}`.

I have checked documents for Youtube API but I can't find that it has restrictions for getting oembed and has authorization too. I can only see a restriction for Youtube Data API.

Why do I get the 403 Forbidden response from this API...?

Sample sending request:

```
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK5tNXJ6Ibo
```

Comment: Please add the samples you're using.

Comment: I've been using this for years and just started getting errors recently.  First they were encoding issues and now 403 errors.  Seems they have changed something.  If I pull it up in a browser it returns just fine

Comment: The sample of the request I sent is `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK5tNXJ6Ibo`.

Comment: Having the same issue. I have http version of the URLs, which used to work fine till a few days ago, and now it returns 403 error with get_headers().

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are making the requests as https ?  The code I have been using is fairly legacy and when I went down through it the requests were http.  Once I updated the code to make the call over https it stopped getting 403 errors.  Seems this was just recently changed a couple days ago.

Comment: Yes, I requested it as HTTPS. I sent the following request.

`https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK5tNXJ6Ibo`

It seems the above request is working well now. But I had gotten the 403 Forbidden response from it a few days ago...

Comment: @Bret Now that oembed is not working, do you have any alternative methods to check existence of a YouTube video?

Comment: I flipped over to using https and was able to get it working for Youtube

Comment: @Bret Thanks. I just changed to HTTPS too and it works now. But at the time of posting my above comment, it definitely did not work. I guess, they applied the change afterwards. HTTP version still returns 403 though.