# Invalid value for HTML attribute 'data-videoid' in tag 'amp-youtube'

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

**Amp-youtube does not support fallback elements in case a video deleted by youtube or url not correct.**

I also post this question on https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/16434

Comment: @bachcha  singh is there any amp-html expert to solve this problem

Comment: What is your question? title and question content does not match. If you are looking for fallback in amp-youtube it is does not work may be in future it is implement by AMP Team. In php you can check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-using-php

Comment: But how can i checked it is deleted by youtube. it is possible to check it.

Comment: in amp you cann't

Comment: Thanks @bachcha singh